# How do I create multiple show and hide toggle buttons using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

Basically I've been trying to use jQuery to show() and hide() a sub navigation in my content. I've found code which shows and hides when a button is clicked, however, I've been trying to make it so that when one nav button is clicked it will open the content below it but when another nav button in that list is clicked after, it will show that content and hide the previous one.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Sub Nav HTML**

```
                        <ul id="subNav">
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="1">
                                    BLOMFIELD ROAD, 2012
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-1.jpg" alt="Blomfield Road 2012" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="2">
                                    KIDDERPORE GARDENS
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-2.jpg" alt="Kidderpore Gardens"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="3">
                                    BLOMFIELD ROAD, 2010
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-3.jpg" alt="Blomfield Road 2010" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="4">
                                    CECILE PARK
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-4.jpg" alt="Cecile Park" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="5">
                                    LANSDOWNE ROAD
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-5.jpg" alt="Landsdowne Road" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="6">
                                    BLOMFIELD ROAD, 2007
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-6.jpg" alt="Blomfield Road 2007" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="showSingle" target="7">
                                    HANOVER TERRACE
                                    <img src="images/sub-nav-7.jpg" alt="Hanover Terrace" />
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                  </div> <!--END OF subHeader -->
```

**Content HTML**

```
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
                      <div class="content">
                          <p class="projHeader">
                              BLOMFIELD ROAD, 2012
                          </p>
                          <div class="sqBox"></div>
                          <p class="address">
                               2012, Little Venice, London W9
                          </p>
                          <p class="jobDescrip">
                              Complete strip out and refurbishment of 
                              a fire damaged Grade II listed 4 storey building. 
                              Including replacement of fire damaged wall 
                              & floor structures, chemical cleaning to 
                              remove smoke odours and reinstatement to 
                              match original fit out.
                          </p>
                          <p class="projectCompletion">
                              <span class="pcCss">PROJECT COMPLETION</span> <br>
                              April 2011 – February 2012 (10 months)
                          </p>
                          <p class="architect">
                              <span class="title">ARCHITECT</span> <br>
                              <span class="company">Metropolitan Development Consultancy Ltd</span> <br>
                              <a href="www.mdclondon.com"> www.mdclondon.com </a>
                          </p>
                          <div class="spec">
                              <ul>
                                  <li> Control 4 automation system </li>
                                  <li> Bespoke joinery by Ottima </li>
                                  <li> High specification M&amp;E services </li>
                                  <li> Lutron Homeworks lighting system </li>
                                  <li> Poggenpohl kitchen by Nicholas Anthony  </li>
                                  <li> Air conditioning, audio visual & underfloor <br>
                                      heating system automated via Control 4 system.  
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                         </div> <!-- END OF spec -->
                        </div> <!-- END OF content -->
                        <div class="slideshow">

                        </div><!-- END OF slideshow -->
                </div><!-- END OF div1 -->
                <div id="div2" class="targetDiv">
                  <div class="content">
                          <p class="projHeader">
                              BLOMFIELD ROAD, 2012
                          </p>
                          <div class="sqBox"></div>
                          <p class="address">
                               2012, Little Venice, London W9
                          </p>
                          <p class="jobDescrip">
                              Complete strip out and refurbishment of 
                              a fire damaged Grade II listed 4 storey building. 
                              Including replacement of fire damaged wall 
                              & floor structures, chemical cleaning to 
                              remove smoke odours and reinstatement to 
                              match original fit out.
                          </p>
                          <p class="projectCompletion">
                              <span class="pcCss">PROJECT COMPLETION</span> 
                              April 2011 – February 2012 (10 months)
                          </p>
                          <p class="architect">
                              <span class="title">ARCHITECT</span> <br>
                              <span class="company">Metropolitan Development Consultancy Ltd</span> <br>
                              <a href="www.mdclondon.com"> www.mdclondon.com </a>
                          </p>
                          <div class="spec">
                              <ul>
                                  <li> Control 4 automation system </li>
                                  <li> Bespoke joinery by Ottima </li>
                                  <li> High specification M&amp;E services </li>
                                  <li> Lutron Homeworks lighting system </li>
                                  <li> Poggenpohl kitchen by Nicholas Anthony  </li>
                                  <li> Air conditioning, audio visual & underfloor <br>
                                      heating system automated via Control 4 system.  
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div> <!-- END OF spec -->
                        </div> <!-- END OF content -->
                        <div class="slideshow">

                        </div><!-- END OF slideshow -->
                    </div> <!--END OF kpg -->
```

Comment: There is something missing in the translation here.  What exactly do you want shown for each button clicked?  It would be fairly simple to do if there was a correlation from the target to the thing you want shown. More info would be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice solution called accordion is provided in jQuery addon: jQuery UI.
Try to see this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible writing some extra jQuery:

When you click on a new item, you can traverse its siblings and see if anyone of them are currently active. The just switch class of that active sibling to *inactive*, and make the currently clicked item **active**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Rwx7P/3/)**. It's merely an example to show you the jQuery involved to toggle the content of an article and you should adapt it to fit your specific case.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="article">
    <h1>TITLE 1</h1>
    <div class="content">content 1</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <h1>TITLE 2</h1>
    <div class="content">content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <h1>TITLE 3</h1>
    <div class="content">content 3</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <h1>TITLE 4</h1>
    <div class="content">content 4</div>
</div>
```

​
**CSS**:

```
.content{
 display:none;
 margin: 10px;   
}

h1{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-wieght: bold;
    color: gray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
}
h1:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 color: black;   
}
```

**jQuery**:

```
$("h1").on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).children("div"));
    $(this).siblings("div.content").slideToggle();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to show and hide those `targetDiv`s? If so, you can use something like

```
$('a.showSingle').click(function(e){ 
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $('div.targetDiv').hide().filter('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/TqtXz/